# How To Count Every User And Return Array In Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

[image: Image Database here]

I have Database like this and want the return like :

```
id_user : 5c348f8041dc5 have 2  
id_user : 5cfc8a7d33a12 have 1
```

How to do that or the name of the tutorial that I should look for?

Thanks.

Comment: What is 2 and 1?

Comment: the result of Count id_user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `COUNT` and a `group_by` statement.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

```
function test() {

    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->select('id_user, COUNT(*) as total');
    $this->db->from('test'); // replace 'test' with your database table
    $this->db->group_by('id_user');
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() == 0) {
        show_error('no rows');
    }

    foreach ($q->result() as $item) {
        echo "id_user: $item->id_user have $item->total <br>";
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]